# Flask-SQLAlchemy database engine returns table names, but the table keys in metadata are empty

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am connected to a MS SQL Server. The following returns all the table names in the database:

```
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

db.engine.table_names()
```

However, this doesn't:

```
db.metadata.tables.keys() // returns: dict_keys([])
```

Similarly, this doesn't work:

```
db.table('dbo.users').primary_key // returns: ColumnSet([])
```

However, I am able to execute SQL queries. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Engine.table_names`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.table_names) gives you a list of *available* table names from the database. [`Metadata.tables`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.tables) is a mapping of *declared* tables associated with the metadata.

If you want to populate the metadata with what's available in the database, use [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html):

```
db.metadata.reflect(bind=db.engine)
```